# Prove $A_t := W_t^3-3t W_t$ a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Given prob space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ and a Wiener process $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$, define filtration $\mathscr{F}_t = \sigma(W_u : u \leq t)$

Let $(A_t)_{t \geq 0}$ where $A_t = W_t^3 - 3tW_t$. Show that $E[A_t|\mathscr{F}_s] = A_s$ whenever $s < t$.

I think this all comes down to manipulation since there are martingales somewhere

My attempt:

Splitting up into $E[W_t^3|\mathscr{F}_s] - 3E[tW_t|\mathscr{F}_s]$ doesn't do anything since those guys aren't martingales? So, I tried splitting it up into:

$E[W_t(W_t^2 - 3t)|\mathscr{F}_s]$

$= E[W_t(W_t^2 - t -2 t)|\mathscr{F}_s]$

$= E[W_t(W_t^2 - t) -2 tW_t)|\mathscr{F}_s]$

$= E[W_t(W_t^2 - t)|\mathscr{F}_s] -2E[ tW_t|\mathscr{F}_s]$

$W_t$ is not $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable, so we can't take that out...

$tW_{1/t}$ is Brownian and thus a martingale, but I don't know about $tW_t$...

$cW_{t/c^2}$ is Brownian and thus a martingale, but I don't think we can set c = t...

Help please?

Comment: Unable to identify $E[tW_t|\mathscr{F}_s]$? Well, we have a problem of learning curve here...

Comment: @Did Is it Wiener?

Comment: @BCLC What's the variance of $t W_t$?

Comment: @saz $t^2 Var(W_t)$ ? ...OOOOHHHH HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Comment: @Did Very funny, Did. Okay got it. Just take out t. Haha

Comment: @BCLC ?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: @saz I assumed you were leading me to realize that I could take out t?

Comment: That's what Did was after. My thought was different: Since $\text{var} \, (t W_t) = t^3$, $(tW_t)_{t \geq 0}$ cannot be a Brownian motion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing

$$W_t^3 = ((W_t-W_s)+W_s)^3 = (W_t-W_s)^3+ 3 W_s (W_t-W_s)^2 + 3 W_s^2 (W_t-W_s) + W_s^3$$

we find using the independence of the increments

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(W_t^3 \mid \mathcal{F}_s) &= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((W_t-W_s)^3)}_{\mathbb{E}(W_{t-s}^3)=0} + 3W_s \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_t-W_s)^2}_{\mathbb{E}(W_{t-s}^2)=t-s} + 3W_s^2 \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_t-W_s)}_{0}+W_s^3 \\ &= 3(t-s) W_s + W_s^3. \end{align*}$$

Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}(A_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(W_t^3 - 3t W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = 3(t-s)W_s+ W_s^3 - 3t \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s)}_{W_s} = A_s.$$

A general remark: If you want to prove a process of this form a martingale, it is always a good idea to write $$W_t = (W_t-W_s)+W_s$$ and separate both terms, since this allows us to use the independence of the increments (which in turn makes calculation of conditional expectations much more easier).

Comment: Satisfying the martingale property makes it martingale? Aren't there other conditions or something?

Comment: Like integrable or something? Oh and thanks!

Comment: @BCLC Yes, it has to be integrable. Note that $\mathbb{E}(W_t^k)<\infty$ for any $k$ as $W_t \sim N(0,t)$.

Comment: Why is $E[(W_t-W_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[(W_t-W_s)^3]=0$?

Comment: @user428487 Because $W_t-W_s$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_s$.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to use Itô Formula : $$\mathrm d (W_t^3-3tW_t)=3W_t^2\,\mathrm d W_t+3W_t\,\mathrm d t-3t\,\mathrm dW_t-3W_t\mathrm dt,$$
i.e. $$W_t^3-3tW_t=\int_0^t 3(W_t^2-t)\,\mathrm d W_t.$$

By Fubini, $$\mathbb E\int_0^T(W_t^2-t)^2\,\mathrm d t=\int_0^T\mathbb E[(W_t^2-t)^2]\,\mathrm d t<\infty ,$$ and thus, it's indeed a martingale.

Comment: A quick question, why can we interchange E and the integral? Do we need to invoke DCT or something similar?

Comment: @jmac: As written, it's Fubini's theorem...

Comment: I apologize. Just to be clear: We can use Fubini when the double integral converges and thus switch the order of the integrals. But why does the double integral converge? I can see the inner integral (wrt time) clearly is finite and well-defined (positive continuous, integrand over a finite interval) but why should the double integral itself be finite?

Answer (score 2):

This is a settled question but I like to add another solution :-)

We have $W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s \sim \mathcal{N}(W_s,t-s)$ hence using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) we have $$\mathbb{E}(W_t^3 \mid \mathcal{F}_s)=W_s^3+3W_s(t-s).$$

Therefore \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(W_t^3 - 3t W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s)&=\mathbb{E}(W_t^3 \mid \mathcal{F}_s)-3t\mathbb{E}( W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s)\\
&=W_s^3+3W_s(t-s)-3tW_s\\
&=W_s^3-3sW_s.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Math-fun! ^-^ strange notation though? Is a random variable conditioned on a sigma-algebra also another random variable? :|

Comment: Interesting, I thought till now that we define conditional probabilities with respect to sigma fields. or maybe I do not understand :-)

Comment: Well I'll assume it's just shorthand. :P