# Is it true that $\int_0^t W_s ds = tW_t?$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Given a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t\geq 0},$ it is well-known that $W_t^3$ is not a Brownian motion as its SDE
$$d(W_t^3) = 3W_t^2 dW_t + 3W_t dt$$
contains a nonzero drift term.
To make it to be a martingale, one can consider
$$W_t^3 - 3\int_0^t W_s ds.$$
On the other hand, this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962613/prove-a-t-w-t3-3t-w-t-a-martingale) shows that $W_t^3 - 3tW_t$ is a martingale.

> Question: Is it true that
> $$\int_0^t W_s ds = tW_t?$$

I have a feeling that they are no equal as LHS is deterministic whereas RHS is random.

Answer (score 5):

Both are random. However, LHS is differentiable whereas RHS is not, hence they are not equal.

Comment: Why is LHS differentiable?

Comment: It is the antiderivative of a continuous function

Comment: (Nearly) equivalently, the LHS is Markov and the RHS is not.

Answer (score 3):

Applying integration by parts (which is a standard results in Stochastic Calculus) to $t W_t$ we obtain:

$$ d(t W_t) = t dW_t + W_tdt + d[t,W_t],$$
where $[t,W_t]$ is the quadratic covariation of $t$ and $W_t$. Therefore, expressing the above equation in integral form we obtain

$$ t W_t = \int_0^t s dW_s + \int_0^tW_sds + [t,W_t]$$
Quadratic covariation of a process of finite variation $t$ with a Brownian motion (or more generally with an Ito process) is $0$. Thus, we obtain that

$$ t W_t = \int_0^t s dW_s + \int_0^tW_sds$$

Note that this last equation implies that $t W_t - \int_0^tW_sds$ is a martingale. But being a martingale, does not mean that $t W_t - \int_0^tW_sds=0$.